# Task information is not getting displayed in form

Tags: java, soa, jdeveloper, bpel

I am using worklist application in SOA 11g (BPEL application). After creating the task. when I am trying to see the task details from worklist application. A blank window appears and following set of exception comes in console.

```
<Jun 15, 2011 6:43:02 PM SGT> <Alert> <Diagnostics> <BEA-320016> <Creating diagnostic image in c:\oracle\middleware\user_projects\domains\ura_domain\s
ervers\soa_server1\adr\diag\ofm\ura_domain\soa_server1\incident\incdir_71 with a lockout minute period of 1.>
<Jun 15, 2011 6:43:25 PM SGT> <Warning> <oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFContext> <BEA-000000> <Found wrong applictionScope sticking to oldContext for
 oldApplication worklistapp, while the current one is DAMSTASK>
<Jun 15, 2011 6:43:25 PM SGT> <Warning> <oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFContext> <BEA-000000> <Found wrong applictionScope sticking to oldContext for
 oldApplication worklistapp, while the current one is DAMSTASK>
<Jun 15, 2011 6:43:25 PM SGT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@19485003[app:DAMSTASK module:/workflow/DAMSTASK path:/workflow/DAMSTASK spe
c-version:2.5], request: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl@17e5278[
GET /workflow/DAMSTASK/faces/adf.task-flow?bpmWorklistTaskId=12b26962-7809-4308-9b12-d8fedea4be86&bpmWorklistContext=c7dd6e73-f659-43c1-9e34-12a3817b8
e36%3B%3BpbXxzFTSG5zZzkmHvJcmUEn%2BUffmLBx%2FSLAyeHg%2BjOLY%2FOJ%2FeQAl6ws2vsKoSDwSkM9K9HAaRdQhs90dxRAfM%2FjduV0MSxscGV3I0pupJIVpb%2F2R%2BvbuYJfqIFA2W
I%2BibofdeKDKIf4dhoWGp0DijdifOXns3%2BGNfpb7B2nS3ikiwiC%2BZ%2BkV08ge6YBA80uNikQXyTKjcOPbx3usc8hRFFVQmCpqR39mL2hgiEzBDdwv1A%2B9f36eLM33uSykFbkp&parentUR
L=http%3A%2F%2F172.16.10.116%3A8001%2Fintegration%2Fworklistapp%2Ffaces%2Fhome.jspx&bpmWorklistHttpURL=http%3A%2F%2F172.16.10.116%3A8001%2Fintegration
%2Fworklistapp%2Ffaces&bpmWorklistHome=home.jspx&bpmWorklistLogout=login.jspx&bpmWorklistLogin=login.jspx&bpmWorklistReassign=reassignTask.jspx&bpmWor
klistRoute=routeTask.jspx&bpmWorklistRequestInfo=requestInfo.jspx&bpmWorklistTreeHistory=treeHistory.jspx&bpmWorklistHistory=treeHistory.jspx&bpmWorkl
istBackPage=home.jspx&bpmWorklistSecurity=signTask.jspx&tz=Asia%2FSingapore&lg=en&cy=US&vr=&df=medium&dt=both&tf=short&bpmWorklistSessionTimeoutInterv
al=300&_id=DamsTask_TaskFlow&_document=WEB-INF%2FDamsTask_TaskFlow.xml&_afrLoop=25873110242572&_afrWindowMode=0&_afrWindowId=null HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: en-us
UA-CPU: x86
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2)
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=SK7sN4MTVnZ3ZXQmgm0mTRpG9yYMVKv4zlWXzvypnGC4WWtfwyyy!-1490389621

]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration.<init>(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilerConfiguration;)V
        at oracle.jbo.ExprEval.parseScript(ExprEval.java:710)
        at oracle.jbo.ExprEval.findScript(ExprEval.java:669)
        at oracle.jbo.ExprEval.doEvaluate(ExprEval.java:860)
        at oracle.jbo.ExprEval.evaluateForRow(ExprEval.java:761)
        at oracle.jbo.server.AttributeDefImpl.evaluateTransientExpression(AttributeDefImpl.java:2029)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

I have checked the Administration URI for task also.
please help me to resolve the issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems your installation is broken, the Groovy classes on the class path are not of the right version. You should check if it's

- either in the app server's lib folder or
- should be bundled with the war/ear

Comment: thanks, But the same set up was working some day before. Today I just changed the version of process and deploy. Its started showing blank screen...I am not sure where is the poison inside. I did not alter any jar and files.